# Empty Stack Exception in Java

Tags: java, stack, lisp, calculator

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this code, so I was hoping I could get some more experienced eyes to review it for me.

This is my Stack Trace:

```
input an expression string:(+ 1 2)
Evaluate expression #1 :(+ 1 2)
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
at java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
at PJ2.SimpleLispExpressionEvaluator.evaluateCurrentOperation(SimpleLispExpressionEvaluator.java:126)
at PJ2.SimpleLispExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SimpleLispExpressionEvaluator.java:235)
at PJ2_Test.main(PJ2_Test.java:42)
Java Result: 1
```

This is line 126:

```
while(tokenStack.peek() instanceof Double){
```

This is line 235:

```
evaluateCurrentOperation();
```

This is my current code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class StackCalculator{

private String currentExpression;

// Main expression stack, see algorithm in evaluate()
private Stack<Object> tokenStack;

public SimpleLispExpressionEvaluator()
{
    tokenStack = new Stack();
    currentExpression = "";
}

// constructor with an input expression 
public SimpleLispExpressionEvaluator(String inputExpression) 
{
    tokenStack = new Stack();
    tokenStack.push(inputExpression);
    currentExpression = inputExpression;
}

public void reset(String inputExpression) 
{
    currentExpression = inputExpression;
    //tokenStack.clear();
    //tmpStack.clear();

    //not working for some reason
}


// This function evaluates current operator with its operands
// See complete algorithm in evaluate()
//
// Main Steps:
//      Pop operands from tokenStack and push them onto 
//          tmpStack until you find an operator
//      Apply the operator to the operands on tmpStack
//          Push the result into tokenStack
//
private void evaluateCurrentOperation()
{
    Stack<Double> tmpStack=new Stack<Double>();
    double a=0.0;
    while(!tokenStack.isEmpty()){
        while(!tokenStack.isEmpty()){
        if(tokenStack.peek() instanceof Double){
            tmpStack.push((Double)tokenStack.pop());
        }else if(tokenStack.peek() instanceof Character){
        if(!tokenStack.isEmpty()){
        switch((Character)tokenStack.pop()){
            case '+':
                while(!tmpStack.isEmpty()){
                    a += tmpStack.pop();
                }
                tokenStack.push(a);
            break;
            case '-':
                while(!tmpStack.isEmpty()){
                    a -= tmpStack.pop();
                }
                tokenStack.push(a);
            break;    
            case '*':
                while(!tmpStack.isEmpty()){
                    a *= tmpStack.pop();
                }
                tokenStack.push(a);
            break;
            case '/':
                while(!tmpStack.isEmpty()){
                    a /= tmpStack.pop();
                }
                tokenStack.push(a);
            break;
    }
}
}
}

/**
 *
 * The algorithm:  
 *
 * Step 1           Scan the tokens in the string.
 * Step 2       If you see an operand, push operand object onto the tokenStack
 * Step 3           If you see "(", next token should be an operator
 * Step 4       If you see an operator, push operator object onto the tokenStack
 * Step 5       If you see ")"  // steps in evaluateCurrentOperation() :
 * Step 6       Pop operands and push them onto tmpStack until you find an operator
 * Step 7       Apply the operator to the operands on tmpStack
 * Step 8       Push the result into tokenStack
 * Step 9           If you run out of tokens, the value on the top of tokenStack is the result of the expression.
 */
public double evaluate()
{
    Scanner currentExpressionScanner = new Scanner(currentExpression);
    double finRes = 0.0;
    currentExpressionScanner = currentExpressionScanner.useDelimiter("\\s*");
// Step 1: Scan the tokens in the string.
    while (currentExpressionScanner.hasNext())
    {
// Step 2: If you see an operand, push operand object onto the tokenStack
        if (currentExpressionScanner.hasNextInt())
        {
            // This force scanner to grab all of the digits
            // Otherwise, it will just get one char
            String dataString = currentExpressionScanner.findInLine("\\d+");
            tokenStack.push(Double.parseDouble(dataString));
        }
        else
        {
            // Get next token, only one char in string token
            String aToken = currentExpressionScanner.next();
            //System.out.println("Other: " + aToken);
            char item = aToken.charAt(0);


            switch (item)
            {
// Step 3: If you see "(", next token should be an operator
                case '(':
                    String nextToken = currentExpressionScanner.next();
                    if(!nextToken.equals("+")&&!nextToken.equals("- ")&&!nextToken.equals("*")&&!nextToken.equals("/")){
                    throw new LispExpressionException("After this " + item + " should be an operator");
                    }
                    break;
// Step 4: If you see an operator, push operator object onto the tokenStack
                case '+':
                    tokenStack.push(item);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    tokenStack.push(item);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    tokenStack.push(item);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    tokenStack.push(item);
                    break;
// Step 5: If you see ")"  // steps in evaluateCurrentOperation() :
                case ')':
                    evaluateCurrentOperation();
                    break;
                default:  // error
                    throw new LispExpressionException(item + " is not a legal expression operator");
            } // end switch
        } // end else
    } // end while

// Step 9: If you run out of tokens, the value on the top of tokenStack is
//         the result of the expression.
//         return result
    while(!tokenStack.isEmpty()){
    if(tokenStack.peek() instanceof Character){
        throw new LispExpressionException(tokenStack.pop() + " is not a number!");
    }else{
        finRes = (Double)tokenStack.pop();
    }
    }
return finRes; // return correct answer!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, looking at your code, it seems quite obvious. If the `tokenStack` only contains doubles, it will eventually get empty as you keep removing the objects from it. When it's empty, the `peek()` call will throw an exception.

```
while(tokenStack.peek() instanceof Double){
      tmpStack.push((Double)tokenStack.pop());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It compiles now! I agree I should of been able to spot that but I'm pretty new to coding and appreciate the help the people in this forum are providing. The code runs now, but it doesn't evaluate the result correctly. I'm going to go back and look it over more. I updated the code to what it is now.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it obvious? The stack is empty, and you're trying to peek into it, which is what this error is telling you.  Somehow, you're not actually pushing anything onto the stack before you're trying to peek at it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EmptyStackException.html